# Correct way to use TWCS (Time compaction) for time series

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I am receiving lot of data from several devices

- Partiton key ( device, bucket(which is 1 week))  => might be months for smaller tables

I can get data as old as 15-20 days which will go in appropriate partition based on date. My table dosent have TTL ie all paritions will live for long though older partitions will be updated really rately

I am not sure what if Timecompaction is right stratgy for me? If yes how should i go about choosing configurations?

Comment: If your partition key is (device, week) and you want last 15-20 days for a device, can't you do 4 reads i.e. (device, current week), (device, last week), (device, 2 weeks ago), etc? Not sure what this has to do with compaction. 

(EDIT) Maybe I misunderstood the question - are you asking what's the optimal compaction strategy to use for this dataset?

Comment: Yes.. I am asking whats optimal strategy. Would layered do ok ? Mostly i will get data 10-15 days older sometimes may be a month

Comment: Without TTL, using TWCS and DTCS are ruled out since storage grows unbounded. What's the read vs write workload ratio, and how many devices? If it's mostly writes or there are many devices, you could use STCS. If high read or updates to small number of devices, can use LCS. From reading https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlHowDataMaintain.html#dmlHowDataMaintain__dml_which_compaction_strategy_is_best